# Disappearing discspace in 21.10

Tags: disk-usage, 21.10

I have the problem that my space is running out. I am running a docker, which needs several gb of data.
This was usually fine until I recently ran out of discspace.

Having everything shut down and trying to pinpoint issues I get to this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           3,2G  2,4M  3,2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p7  348G  296G   35G  90% /
tmpfs            16G  7,2M   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   39M  473M   8% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3,2G  124K  3,2G   1% /run/user/1000
```

File Scan says home: 25.9GB
total: 50.5GB
as used space.

So now I am wondering, where all my space went. I wasn't able to find it.
Using `du`, it said my biggest file is the swapfile with
`2,1G   /swapfile`

Has anyone an idea, how and where I might look for my missing 250GB?
I was expecting a bloated logfile somewhere but got nothing so far.

Comment: Just an FYI:   Don't forget [Ubuntu 21.10 is in it's last days of *support*](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) so plan your time to *release-upgrade* whilst you have *days* left, and not *hours*.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did actually miss that.

Answer (score 0):

You get more information of the disk usage if you use the disk analyzer with sudo rights.
It just seemed to me, that it showed everything.

```
sudo -i
baobab
```

Then I was able to pinpoint the culprit.